# How to combine data model types with document ids?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Firestore and Typescript.

For the data models I have types definitions. For example `User` could be this:

```
interface User {
 name: string;
 age: number;
}
```

The users are stored in the database in the `users` collection under a unique name/id.

In Firebase when you query a collection, the ids of the documents are available on the document reference, and do not come with the data. In a common use-case for front-end, you want to retrieve an array of records with their ids, because you probably want to interact with them and need to identify each.

So I made a query similar to the code below, where the id is merged into the resulting array:

```
async function getUsers(): Promise<any[]> {
  const query = db.collection("users")

  const snapshot = await query.get();

  const results = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
  });
}
```

Now the problem is, that I have a User type, but it can't be used here because it does not contain an `id` field.

A naïve solution could be to create a new type:

```
interface UserWithId extends User {
  id: string
}
```

And write the function like:

```
async function getUsers(): Promise<UserWithId[]> {}
```

But this doesn't feel right to me, because you would have to potentially do this for many types.

A better solution I think would be to create a generic type:

```
type DatabaseRecord<T> = {
  id: string,
  data: T
}
```

Thus keeping data and ids separate in the returning results:

```
const results = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
  return { data: doc.data(), id: doc.id };
});
```

... and use the function signature:

```
async function getUsers(): Promise<DatabaseRecord<User>[]> {}
```

I would favour the second over the first solution, because creating new types for each case feels silly. But I am still not sure if that is the best approach.

This seems like such a common scenario but I didn't manage to find any documentation on this. I have seen developers simply write the `id` in the model data, essentially duplicating the document name in its data, but that to me seems like a big mistake.

I can imagine that if you don't use Typescript (of Flow) that you just don't care about the resulting structure and simply merge the id with the data, but this is one of the reasons I really love using type annotation in JS. It forces you think more about your data and you end up writing cleaner code.

Comment: Did you find any answers to this? For the tutorials I've read, they only handle the documents and access any properties over the "data()" function. See https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/angular-crud-with-firebase for example. It doesn't make so much sense to me either.

Comment: No not really. I have been using the approach outlined above. Only now I call it `Document<T>` instead of `DatabaseRecord<T>`. I have come across one library that took a similar approach. I think it's the only sensible solution I can think of. I've come across libraries that just merged the id into the document data, but that's just messy and those were unsurprisingly also not using Typescript :)

Comment: And if you *do* want to merge the id into the data type you can do this: `type UserDocument = User & { id: string }`, but like I said I don't see any reason why you would want to do this.